# Vim: is there a command to switch windows

Tags: vim

I need a `:` command to switch windows because I'm using it in a function. so `<C-W>W` won't do.

Comment: oh no I can use `wincmd w` didn't know that.

Comment: Why does `normal <c-w>w` fail?

Comment: @CiroSantilli because I'm using it from a vim function. I tried `normal! <c-w>w` but this doesn't not work

Comment: It does not work for me either, I wanted to understand why =)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using:

```
wincmd k
```

I got what I needed

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with using `normal <C-w>w` in a function as well.

My problem was that I ran it within `execute` where you need to escape the first angle bracket, resulting in `execute("normal \<C-w>w")`. Hope this still helps some people understand it.

For more help use `:help normal` and `:help execute` in Vim